# iOS: URLSession: Does anyone know about the cycle in which this function is invoked?

Tags: ios, swift

I wondered what cycle the Delegate function of URLSession would be called.

```
urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
```

Do you know what kind of periodics this function works with?

I was curious because Apple's official document also simply said "Periodic."

Answer (score 0):

It actually proportional to your network bandwidth and disproportional to network delay and packet dropped. The more bandwidth, less delay and less packet dropped, the more frequent of this method called.

I have tried to download same file with different network profile for `60 seconds` and here is the result.

```
Wifi:
    Bandwidth: 40mbps
    Packet Dropped: 0%
    Delay: 1ms
    Number of calls: 445

3G:
    Bandwidth: 780kbps
    Packet Dropped: 0%
    Delay: 100ms
    Number of calls: 230

Very Bad Network:
    Bandwidth: 1mbps
    Packet Dropped: 10%
    Delay: 100ms
    Number of calls: 13
```